# Updating WooCommerce variable product stock issue

Tags: plugins, php, woocommerce-offtopic, sql, cron

Soo.. I've created CRON script, that each 1 minute retrieves an actual stock systems data, converts it for Wordpress/Woocommerce database table and updates stock.

On database side everything looks right and works (*see 1st screenshot*), but in WP Admin Panel only parent/main variable product inventory data shows as updated - it SUMS all variation STOCK quantities (*see 2nd screenshot*). **However he STOCK quantity data in Variations section for different sizes doesn't seem to be updated (*see 3rd screenshot*).**

Soo I was wondering.. is there some kind of Caching that WooCommerce is using? And if so.. how can I clear it? Because so far I've cleared all the cache there is, but Variation stock still stays 0.

### Screenshots & Descriptions

**Database after update** - Stock CRON script updates Variation stock (double checked, works for all Variations and main parent Variable product Inventory STOCK - it sums all Variations STOCKS)
[image: Database Screenshot]

**Product variation after update** - Stock CRON DID update this value, but it still shows 0.
[image: Variation Product Screenshot]

**Variable/Parent product after update** - Stock CRON did update the stock - SUMS up all variations STOCK quantitys and updates it here.
[image: Variable/Parent Product Screenshot]

I've double checked everything. CRON script is fine - as you can see from screenshots it does update data in database. The issue here is only that it doesn't show it in front for Variations of products.

A help would be much apreciated! :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try updating the variation stock in the backend, and see what it stores in the DB. I think there is a meta value like `_variable_stock`

Comment: @Pim Unfortunately there is no such `meta_key` in postmeta table.

Comment: could you share your code with us ?

Comment: @nikosvl97 its been 2 years already. I don't have the source code. Also the issue was with Redis Object Caching. If you're referring to stock update cron - try googling. [Here's first result i got regarding this situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51204251/scheduling-wp-cron-job-to-update-products-meta-daily).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some hours of investigation I deactivated W3 Total Cache plugin. Still no changes. And then I noticed WP Redis plugin.. soo I searched for Redis Object Caching on serverside and found it. When I flushed the cache, the stock showed updated stock quantity.

Soo.. always double-check your caching. :D